# Test network completely removed from the real network?

Tags: development, testnet, regtest

I know of the testnet Bitcoin provides, but is there any framework or simulator of the Bitcoin network which I can use to test on my local machine? I would like to edit parts of the code and simulate the responses of the real network without actually interacting with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in the Bitcoin Developer Guide on Testing Applications. The section you are interested in is likely to be [Regtest](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testing-applications).